# Add same image repeatedly but retrieve the image only once

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pdf-generation, reportlab, platypus

The aim is to avoid repeating the GET call since it's the same image. Therefore I'd like to store it and reuse it. However, it doesn't work as I expected because the call is done on the `append()`. For example:

```
from reportlab.platypus import Image
doc = SimpleDocTemplate()

image = Image('http://localhost:8080/photos/13012/small.jpg')
for i in range (0, 3):
    story.append(image)
doc.build(story)
```

You'd get a `GET` call on each iteration. I have also tried using `BaseDocTemplate` and `Canvas`, but no joy so far. Has anybody ever achieved what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Get the image with `urllib2` like they do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286502/how-can-i-add-a-png-to-a-pdf-with-report-lab) and use as a local file.